# How do I know which Group Ids are already registered in the Maven Repository?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, sonatype

How do I know which Group Ids are already registered in the Maven Repository?

I recently tried to publish a plugin in the Maven Repository, however, I got the message that the GroupId I used in the project was already in use. I searched the internet to find out which GroupsIds are already registered, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your actual question

I'm not aware of any specific list of all Group IDs, but you can check by searching for individual groups at https://search.maven.org/, using the `g:` query operator.

For instance, to find anything published by `com.saucelabs`, you can search for `g:com.saucelabs`, which returns [this list](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.saucelabs).

#### A followup question

Maven requires that the Group ID follows the [Java package naming rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/packages.html#7.7).  That means "*it starts with a reversed domain name you control*".  This isn't always the case for legacy projects, but they warn that new projects not following this rule might find it difficult to get included in the repo.

If you *do* belong to an organisation controlling that group, you'll need to collaborate with the existing publishers in your organization to get permissions to deploy new artifacts with the same group, and likely add a new subgroup (eg, `com.saucelabs.examples` is a subgroup of `com.saucelabs`)

You can read more about Maven Co-ordinates here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html.

And there are also some Sonatype guidelines here: https://central.sonatype.org/publish/#individual-projects-open-source-software-repository-hosting-ossrh

Comment: Technically, maven doesn't require reverse domain names, but sonatype does. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html